# Creating a Java Swing JFrame with a circular shape?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to make a circular JFrame if possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle has a nice tutorial on exactly this topic:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

**Shaped Windows**

> The other feature introduced in
>   release 6u10 is the window shaping
>   effect. Using shaping you can set any
>   shape to an undecorated window. When
>   the effect is applied, the desired
>   area of a window becomes transparent.
>   Thus, the combination of transparent
>   and non-transparent pixels form the
>   shape of a given window. The next
>   images demonstrate window shaping in
>   two cases:

[Text extracted from original article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/translucent-shaped-windows-139324.html ]