# Swing circular JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

is it possible to make a circular JFrame without the need to the Class AWTUtilities

i mean in jdk 6 .. is it possible??

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "circular" ?

Comment: @Raveline, see Ahmed last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154880/creating-a-java-swing-jframe-with-a-circular-shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWTUtilities can be used in all of JDK 6, and is standard as of update 10.

I would refer you to the same link as before: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

Comment: this guy saying don't use it if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941337/com-sun-awt-package-usage

Comment: @Ahmed, read further, if you are using 6u10 or later there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible without AWT.