# changing the shape of jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, translucency, shaped-window

I don't know whether it is possible or not.Is there any way to change the shape of jframe into circle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swing circular JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156912/swing-circular-jframe)

Comment: You should try to Google some keywords. This is a lesson: "Google is your best friend" (http://tinyurl.com/5ssmucf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially what you have to do is make the outer part of your JFrame rendered surface transparent and then draw your own custom shape in the middle.

This will get you started:

> http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/

And this is a finished implementation:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/shaped-transparent-jframe.aspx

Comment: @vijesh: You see: First Google hit!

Comment: @Martijn Indeed. "I feel lucky". This time google actually did a good job finding what I needed; most of the time it just finds what is popular (or worse: established).

Answer (score 1):

//You can change the shape of JFrame
import java.awt.geom.*;

```
setUndecorated(true);
Ellipse2D.Double E=new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,500,500); //nested class Double## 

 - Heading

 ##
setShape(E);
setVisible(true);
```